# How can I remove tabs in the extension configuration?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

This an extension and I need to know how I can remove this that I have marked here below?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ioBvV.png]

Comment: can you explain, why you want to do that. IMHO it makes no sense. Create an editor with proper rights, so he can only see the fields, he should see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding a new content type to TCA (mind you, you will have to take care of the FE rendering as well):

```
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] = array('New Title', 'tx_newkey');
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['tx_newkey']['showitem'] = '--div--;Social Media Buttons,type,language,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.visibility;visibility';
```

to create something like:

[image]

However, there is an extension which modifies the TCA by essentially creating new content elements and lets you also define the FE rendering: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/wec_contentelements